# How to check the value of CheckBoxList by Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

```
--------------------------------------------
Phone number  : ________________________
Email Address : ________________________
You prefer to receive the notification by:
[ ] SMS [ ] Email 
--------------------------------------------
```

Here's what I have in a .aspx page (I am unable to post a picture), two textboxes and two checkboxes. Those checkboxes are data-bound checkboxes where "SMS" and "Email" are two available values from the database currently.

```
        ckBxPreferredMethod.DataSource = dt;
        ckBxPreferredMethod.DataTextField = "Text";
        ckBxPreferredMethod.DataValueField = "Value";
        ckBxPreferredMethod.DataBind();
```

What I want to do now is, using a **customvalidator**, and JavaScript (client-side validation), I want to make sure that if AND ONLY IF the user check the SMS and Email checkboxes, they'll have to fill in their phone number and Email address, respectively. If they were to leave out SMS unchecked, "Phone number" is an optional field.

I am better at C# as I am with JavaScript, so I have done this on server-side no problem using the following method:

```
        protected void ckBxPreferredMethod_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ckBxPreferredMethod.SelectedValue == "1" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtHPNo.Text.Trim()))
        {
            e.IsValid = false; 
            CVemailAndSMS.ErrorMessage = "You need to enter your phone number if you want to receive by SMS"; 
        }

        if(ckBxPreferredMethod.SelectedValue == "2" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text.Trim())) 
        {
            e.IsValid = false; 
            CVemailAndSMS.ErrorMessage = "You need to enter your email if you want to receive by email"; 
        }
    }
```

The above method works fine. But due to further complications in my program, I'm going to have to move this client-side. So JavaScript is required.

If this involves static checkboxes I wouldn't have had a problem. But with databound checkboxlist I'm just lost as to how I would be able to check the values of the selected checkbox.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Because your data is bound to text field, not checkbox. You can always use html checkbox and javascript to check whether they are selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a little more information to get a decent answer.

Taking a stab at it I think you want to start looking into **conditional validation** using JavaScript.

@SEE: http://www.users.muohio.edu/klumbca/examples/conditional-validation-example.html?hearabout=Newspaper+Ad&hearabout_other=

Notice how you only have to input the text if you have 'Other' marked?

Not vouching for the plugin used but it should point you in the right direction.